# Is there any help why Steam doesn't load up?

Tags: 16.04

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 16.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(0)
libGL error: unable to load driver: radeonsi_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: radeonsi
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

Comment: How did you install steam?  How are you opening it?  What is the error message?

Comment: there is no error message, it doesn't do anything and won't load up, i used software center or software manager to install it, and i reinstalled it with another pacman, but still it doesn't work

Comment: Will you run this command.  Give it about two minutes to process.  Then edit your question and add the content of `~/steam.out` to your question?  The command: `steam > ~/steam.out 2>&1`.

Comment: ok i will do that

Comment: in the terminal?

Comment: Yes.  From the terminal.

Comment: it did nothing??

Comment: Will you run this.  Copy and pastes both the command and the output to your question:  `cat ~/steam.out`.  Make sure we can see the command along with the output it shows in the text you append to the terminal.

Comment: Please edit your question and paste the content into your question.

Comment: Running Steam on ubuntu 16.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(0)
libGL error: unable to load driver: radeonsi_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: radeonsi
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast

Comment: Will you run this `cat ~/steam.out`.  Copy the content of both the command and the output and paste it into your question.  If you would do this, it will make it very easy for me to provide the resolution.  I need to see it in your question.  It might not look formatted correctly.  But as long as you paste the output to your question, I can handle the formatting.  Thanks!

Comment: You removed the previous content of your question.  You not only have details of an error.  For others (besides me who saw the original question) they might be confused as to what you are asking.  I'll work on the resolution.  But you would get better participation from the entire community if your question was clear... not just the error output.

Comment: Will you test if this command will start steam: `LD_PRELOAD='/usr/$LIB/libstdc++.so.6' DISPLAY=:0 steam`?

Comment: ok i think it worked

Comment: Thanks for the testing and reporting.  I'll use this to format my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're having [documented](https://steamcommunity.com/app/221410/discussions/0/617336568068489642/) problems with the AMD drivers.  You can start it by running this from the terminal:

```
$ LD_PRELOAD='/usr/$LIB/libstdc++.so.6' DISPLAY=:0 steam
```

You can also make a script and desktop launcher using these steps:

Edit a startup file (`steam.sh`):

```
$ gedit ~/bin/steam.sh
```

Add this content and save the file:

```
#!/bin/bash
export LD_PRELOAD='/usr/$LIB/libstdc++.so.6'
steam
```

Create the launcher:

```
$ sudo apt install gnome-panel
$ gnome-desktop-item-edit --create-new ~/Desktop
```

For the new launcher use:

```
Type       Application
Name       My Steam
Command    (Click the browse button and browse to the `steam.sh` script.)
Commen     My Customized Steam Launcher
```

Click <kbd>OK</kbd>

Now copy or move the new launcher from your `~/Desktop` to `~/.local/share/applicatons/`

Now you will have two launchers in your Ubuntu Dash Search.  When you run the new one, it will surface as the first one in the list.  The broken one will scroll off after a few launches.